# Redirect to Reset password page, React & aws-amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm working on a project with Aws Cognito, and I'm using their standard UI library to login.
The UI also have a forgot password button, where you can go an change your password, that gets you to this page
[aws amplify reset password page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQRTG.png)

Now, we want to have this option in our app, and we have a button Reset password, somewhere in a user settings Page. And I want to redirect the user to the Page above, but I can't find any way other then log him out, and then he must click on the forget button link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the Amplify documentation. In the following link you have more information about which functions from Amplify Authentication should be called: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js/#change-password